# Tag list filter for posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a filter based on tags but im not sure how to proceed I have the tags being displayed in my post list with their anchor tags.

```
<?php
   $tags = get_tags( array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC') );
   foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) {
   echo '<a href="' . get_tag_link ($tag->term_id) . '" rel="tag">' . $tag->name . ' (' . $tag->count . ') </a>';
 }
 ?></p>
```

I am using the following for my loop to get my posts

```
<?php
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&offset=$debut');
foreach ($myposts as $post):
  setup_postdata($post);
?>
```

So My Questions

1 How do i go about adjusting my get_posts to apply a filter based on tag selection. Would this be easy to do with ajax

2 What is best way to generate the tag link list so that the above can be performed.

**Edit**
What im wanting to do is make sure I just get the url slug from tag/tag-3 how do i get this.

**Edit**
Ok i have made it a bit futher but its still only showing all posts in my tag page even though the single tag title is not blank so what gives ?.

```
<div class="post-list" style="width:80%;float:left">
            <?php

            $tag = single_tag_title('', false);
   echo '<h2>Tag: '.$tag.'</h2>';
  $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => $tag,
        'terms' => $tag,
 );


        $myposts = get_posts($args);
        foreach ($myposts as $post):
            setup_postdata($post);
        ?>
             <div id="dateInfo" style="float:right;">
<?php the_date('Y.m.j'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<?php comments_number( '0 hozzászólás', '1 hozzászólás', '% hozzászólás' ); ?>.
</div>


             <div id="title_wrapper">
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this put your taxonomy and term name here

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'genre',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'jazz'
        )
    )
);
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
```

if you want this done by ajax call then you will have to run an onclick function on `<a>` tags and call the above code in ajax response
this will return you with the tag filtered posts..

> Need to pass **taxonomy** and **terms** by onclick function

Comment: How would i retrieve the tag slug from the url when the tag link is clicked though ?. at present it s going to here http://kvalixhu.digitalthinkersni.co.uk/tag/tag-3/ but still showing all the tags.

Comment: Can you provide an example of this please so i can mark as answer thanks of passing the values by onlcick And intercepting them in that area

Comment: and this does not filter tags this is taxonmoys

Answer (score 0):

Ok so as you have list of `<a>` tags, modify it to :

> Get you taxonomy name and term ID is already coming here. it will be
>   passed in onclick function.

```
<?php
   $tags = get_tags( array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC') );
   foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) {
    $term_ID = $tag->term_id;
    $taxonomy_name = 'GET TAXONOMY NAME HERE';

   echo '<a onclick="show_filter_tags('.$term_ID.','.$taxonomy_name.')" href="' . get_tag_link ($tag->term_id) . '" rel="tag">' . $tag->name . ' (' . $tag->count . ') </a>';
 }
 ?>
```

define the onclick function in the `<a>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show_filter_tags(term_id,taxonomy_name){

        var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
          $.post(
          ajaxurl, 
          {
              'action'  :   'get_tagged_posts',
              'term_id' :   term_id,
              'taxonomy_name' : taxonomy_name,
          }, 
          function(output){
            console.log(output)
          });
      }
</script>
```

Now here is the function where query needs to be written which will filter the posts on basis of tags. Pu this in functions.php file in active theme folder

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_tagged_posts', 'get_tagged_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_tagged_posts', 'get_tagged_posts');
function get_tagged_posts() {
    $args = array(
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $_REQUEST['taxonomy_name'],
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $_REQUEST['term_id'],
                'operator' => 'IN',
            )
        )
    );
    $postslists = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ($postslists as $postslist) {
        # code...
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have been clear im not retireving a specific taxnomey of posts im trying to show all posts based on this filter

Comment: please see edit in my oringal question i just need to get the filter from the url im not really that bothered with ajax at mo

Comment: Prakash can you see my edits above please i just need to get the slug url in posts